# How to get integer from column without using regexp_like

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

I have a Column `X` in `Oracle` that has values like "a1b2c3", "abc", "1ab", "123", "156-346"

how do I write a sql query that returns me only the `X` that hold pure numerical values like `123,456` etc.

I can not using `regexp_like` because I am using `10g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options: one uses regular expressions, another `translate` function.

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'a1b2c3' col from dual union all
  3     select 'abc'        from dual union all
  4     select '1ab'        from dual union all
  5     select '123'        from dual union all
  6     select '156-346'    from dual
  7    )
  8  select col,
  9    regexp_replace(col, '[^[:digit:]]') result,
 10    --
 11    translate(col, '0'|| translate(col, '$0123456789', '$'), '0') result2
 12  from test;

COL     RESULT  RESULT2
------- ------- -------
a1b2c3  123     123
abc
1ab     1       1
123     123     123
156-346 156346  156346

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks . but i can not use regexp_replace and i hv to use this in where clause

Comment: You're welcome. I added another option that uses the TRANSLATE function. See if it helps.

Comment: Actually little foot, if column contains string, it simply needs to ignore it. as of now if one column containing 1 and another column 1abc it is giving true.

Comment: can it give null or 0 if column containing anything other than integer?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `translate` function to remove all the digits and trimming the result, pure numbers will yield `null`

```sql
select x
from test
where trim(translate(x, '0123456789', '          ')) is null;
```

Make sure to have 10 spaces as last parameter to `translate`.

If the `x` column can contain spaces, then use

```sql
select x
from test
where trim(translate(replace(x,' ','*'), '0123456789', '          ')) is null;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/772dc7d/2/0